# Calling a URL on receiving an event from a button click using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I might be asking a very trivial question but I am not able to figure out the solution to this. I do have use case where a third party header is used and on clicking a button of that header it raises an event. On adding event listener in my html I need to update the current URL to a particular URL `"?logout"` using JavaScript. Below is the way I could read the event raised after clicking the button from header but not sure how to get the href updated from this function.

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.addEventListener("buttonClick", (e) => {   
   // change href or URL to "?logout"
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: unclear what a third party header has to do with clicking a button. I am guessing header as an `<header>`? So bind an event to the button and set the window.location to a new location?

Comment: "_I need to update the current URL to a particular URL_" Without navigating to the new URL?

Comment: @Teemu  Yes, that's how SPA's work.

Comment: You can use either `history.replaceState` or `history.pushState` ,,  Use pushState if you want to have history, eg. back button, or replaceState if you want to replace the URL without it adding to the history.

Comment: eg.  try this in your browsers console,.. `history.replaceState({}, '', location.href + '__bob__');`  See how `__bob__` is added to the current url without it re-loading.

Comment: @Keith True, but there's no word about SPA in the question ...

Comment: Do you want to override the event/effect the third party event executes, or just execute your own function afterwards?

Comment: @Teemu  that's true, but I never said there was.

Comment: @epascarello -  Yes there is an <header> tag given by the third party which uses their own library to get their header, now i needed to add my functionality on a button from their header. which i could so since they are raising an event on that button click. but did not know how to get the href change which worked by the below solution given by rajdeep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update `window.localtion.href`

```
window.location.href += '?logout' //this would append as it looks yours is a query string parameter

window.location.href = '?logout' //this would replace, which is unlikely with '?' char
```

Comment: That is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you.